# Create an AllDayEvent using getCalendarById in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to create an AllDayEvent using the getCalendarById without success. The current script I have will run using getDefaultCalendar but as soon as I try to replace with getCalendarById I get an error message, "Action not allowed".

Code.gs:

```
//Numeric IDs for Column values

//Column containing PBG code
var titleId = 3
//Column containing delivery period
  var titleId2 = 5
//Column containing delivery notes
  var descId = 8
//Column containing TimeStamp
  var formTimeStampId = 1
//Column containing Regional Coordinator
  var regionalcoordinatorId = 2
//Column containing certification status
  var certId = 6
//Column containing delivery date
  var delivdateId = 4
//Column containing Delivery Coordinator
  var deliverycoordinatorId = 9
//Column containing dozens
  var dozensId = 7  

//Calendar Id
  var calendarId = "CALENDAR_ID_GOES_HERE"


function sendFormToCalendar() {
//Allow access to spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var lr = rows.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(lr,1,1);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var title = sheet.getRange(lr,titleId,1,1).getValue()+" :: "+sheet.getRange(lr,dozensId,1,1).getValue()+" :: "+sheet.getRange(lr,titleId2,1,1).getValue();

//Increasing content for Description
    var subOn = "Posted:"+sheet.getRange(lr,formTimeStampId,1,1).getValue()+"\n"+"Posted By: "+sheet.getRange(lr,deliverycoordinatorId,1,1).getValue();
    var desc = "Certification:"+sheet.getRange(lr, certId, 1, 1).getValue()+"\n"+sheet.getRange(lr,descId,1,1).getValue()+"\n"+subOn;
    var loc = 'Perry Import-Export SA';  

//Create an all-day event and log the ID
  var date = sheet.getRange(lr,delivdateId,1,1).getValue();
  var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEvent(title, new Date(date),
                                                                 {location: loc, description: desc});
 Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below would be the proper syntax. If the calendar does not exist or you do not have access getCalendarById() will return null.  I'm guessing the error is thrown from createAllDayEvent(). If you break up your call like below you'll be able to better determine where the error is coming from.

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
var event =  cal.createAllDayEvent(title, new Date(date),{location: loc, description: desc});
```

EDIT: In response to comment below:

The simple way to setup write access is to go to calendar settings -> Share this Calendar settings. If your account has "owner" access ("Make changes AND manage sharing" in the calendar setting) you can also do it in code with the advanced calendar service.

```
var scope = Calendar.newAclRuleScope();
scope.type = "user";
scope.value ="user@example.com";

var aclRule = Calendar.newAclRule();
aclRule.scope = scope
aclRule.role = "writer";

// This is shorthand for all of the above
// {"scope":{"value":"user@example.com", "type":"user"}, "role":"writer"}

Calendar.Acl.insert(aclRule, "myCalendarId")
```

Comment: thanks for the syntax. I ran the script without any problems but when I actually tried to complete the process using the Google Form it did not send to the calendar specified. Two things may be causing this(?): 1) there is a domain name preceding the calendar ID; and/or 2) my shared privileges do not include editing, etc. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should use the entire calendarId as it shows up in the calendar settings. If you authorize the script under your account you will need write access to the calendar.

Comment: I believe it is the write access that is the issue. Is there a syntax for that?